# MySQL create temporary fields with values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am fairly familiar with basic SQL commands but I would like some help on doing this query which seems too complicated for me. Not  sure if it is even possible.

I will try explain what I want to do :/

Basically I want to create extra fields in a query which will display 'on' if the right conditions are found in another table.

Table A contains the data for the user. Table B contains the achievements and are linked by the ID.

There are different types of achievements and some are approved and declined. I am trying to get the approved achievements sorted into temporary fields that correspond to the type.

I've provided a example of what I'm trying to do. [Click here to view image](http://nickhunt.org/query.png) As its a tad hard to explain. Also I am trying to do this on MySQL.

Any advice or comments would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks Nick

Comment: I have used this code to get me close to my desired result but only gives me one value in the created fields.

`SELECT *,
if (type='1' AND status='accepted',"on",'') AS A1,
if (type='2' AND status='accepted',"on",'') AS A2,
if (type='3' AND status='accepted',"on",'') AS A3


FROM `tableA` INNER JOIN `tableB` ON tableA.UID = tableB.ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a schema based on your image.  This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.first_name,
  a.surname,
  if (b1.type is null, '', 'on') as A1,
  if (b2.type is null, '', 'on') as A2,
  if (b3.type is null, '', 'on') as A3
FROM `a`
  LEFT JOIN `b` as b1 ON a.id = b1.uid AND b1.type = 1 AND b1.status = 'accepted'
  LEFT JOIN `b` as b2 ON a.id = b2.uid AND b2.type = 2 AND b2.status = 'accepted'
  LEFT JOIN `b` as b3 ON a.id = b3.uid AND b3.type = 3 AND b3.status = 'accepted'
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Result:

```
+----+------------+-----------+----+----+----+
| id | first_name | surname   | A1 | A2 | A3 |
+----+------------+-----------+----+----+----+
|  1 | john       | smith     | on |    |    |
|  2 | david      | russel    | on | on |    |
|  3 | james      | duncan    | on |    | on |
|  4 | gavin      | dow       | on | on |    |
+----+------------+-----------+----+----+----+
```

Here's the data I used:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `a`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `a`
--

INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `first_name`, `surname`) VALUES
(1, 'john', 'smith'),
(2, 'david', 'russel'),
(3, 'james', 'duncan'),
(4, 'gavin', 'dow');

--
-- Table structure for table `b`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `b` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `b`
--

INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `uid`, `type`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'accepted'),
(2, 2, 1, 'accepted'),
(3, 2, 2, 'accepted'),
(4, 4, 1, 'accepted'),
(5, 4, 2, 'accepted'),
(6, 4, 3, 'declined'),
(7, 3, 1, 'accepted'),
(8, 3, 2, 'declined'),
(9, 1, 2, 'declined'),
(10, 3, 3, 'accepted');
```

Comment: That did the trick! Didn't expect to get such a quick response! Thank you very much!!